# Plugin does not exist on 404 page?

Tags: plugin-development, 404

Before I go into detail and share my error logs and plugin details, I'll ask the simple question first:

**When testing my 404 page, no plugin functionality works. Is this intentional?**

Just for testing purposes, I tried to include the index template file in my 404 template:

```
{% include 'index' %}
```

This pulls in the homepage fine, but still causes an error:

> Variable "pluginName" does not exist in "404"...

The following returns 'yes' when legitmately on the homepage, and 'no' when on a 404 page, which uses the *include* I just mentioned.

```
{{ pluginName is defined ? 'yes' : 'no'}}
```

Any insight would be great.

Mark

Comment: There should not be any difference and your plugin / plugin variables should work on 404 just like on any other template. Does Twig / Craft work at all?

Comment: That's the weird thing. Craft/Twig functions work perfectly. {{ craft.request.getLastSegment() }} for example is fine. I'm going to give my plugin the once-over to see if there are any obvious issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is what I get for trying to be clever (lazy)...

I've always begrudged typing in '**craft**.myPlugin...' every time I wanted refer to my plugin, so I set a Route Variable in my plugin like so:

```
  craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(
    array(
      'myPlugin' => craft()->myPlugin, 
    )
  );
```

It would appear none of my route variables work in the 404 template. That in itself is a bit odd, so to accomodate my laziness I've added this to the top of my 404 code:

```
{% set myPlugin = craft.myPlugin %}
```

It would be interesting to know if this choice has any detrimental effects? *(besides being looked down upon by my peers)*

Comment: I just found this discussion: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/do-404s-get-access-to-variables-set-with-setroutevariables

Comment: Alternative idea: expose your plugin variables as [Twig globals](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a new variable available globally, you should do it by registering a new Twig extension, using the [addTwigExtension](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addTwigExtension) hook. You can use the Twig extension’s [getGlobals()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Extension.html#method_getGlobals) method to create whatever new global variables you want.